# Move Data Based on a second tables values

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Tech:** SQL Server Management Studio 2012

**Stuck on:** The WHERE part of the process.

**Aim:**

1. Archive data from live system based on new import data using Col1 and Col2 as reference (held in TblImportData)
2. Remove archived data from Live system
3. Move Imported data to Live

**Example workflow:**

```
TblData     

Col1 Col2   Col3
1    Horse  Brown
1    Cat    Ginger
2    Fish   Gold
2    Dog    White
3    Cat    Mixed
3    Cat    Black
3    Fish   Yellow
```

---

```
TblImport       

Col1  Col2       Col3
1     Elephant  Grey
```

---

```
TblDataAFTERSQL     

Col1    Col2   Col3
1    Elephant  Grey
2    Fish      Gold
2    Dog       White
3    Cat       Mixed
3    Cat       Black
3    Fish      Yellow
```

---

```
TblArchiveAFTERSQL      

1   Horse   Brown
1   Cat     Ginger
```

---

The query is:

```
 INSERT INTO [DBArchive].dbo.TblDataArchive  ([Col1],[Col2],[Col3]) 
    SELECT  [Col1],[Col2],[Col3]
    FROM  [DBLive].dbo.TblData
    WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT [Col1],[Col2] FROM [DBImport].dbo.TblImportData)
```

Comment: Why -1? Ask anything you need. I can add links but that is where I got to. The majority works, it is the WHERE part I am stuck on.

Comment: Sample data and desired results really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: Done, need to look up how to make it look nicer mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO [DBArchive].dbo.TblDataArchive  ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3]) 
    SELECT [Col1], [Col2], [Col3]
    FROM [DBLive].dbo.TblData td
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [DBImport].dbo.TblImportData tid
                  WHERE tid.[Col1] = td.[Col1] AND tid.[Col2] = td.[Col2]
                 );
```

Comment: wouldn't a left join, where is null perform better in this specific case (since you're referencing the main columns in the where clause

Comment: Thanks! Should it be TID.[Col1] = td.[Col1] ?

Comment: @SQLMason what are you thinking then? All ears for improvements!

Comment: @indofraiser . . . Yes, you are correct.  As for performance vs a `LEFT JOIN`.  If you care about performance, be sure you have an index on `TblImportData(Col1, Col2)`.  The two methods should be pretty comparable.